# TestDome Data Science: Not getting correct answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I tried to answer this [question](https://www.testdome.com/questions/data-science/marketing-costs/11855?questionIds=13588,11855&generatorId=65&type=fromtest&testDifficulty=Easy) from TestDome and got 250877.19298245612 instead of 250000 as suggested. Please let me what went wrong. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

class MarketingCosts:

    # param marketing_expenditure list. Expenditure for each previous campaign.
    # param units_sold list. The number of units sold for each previous campaign.
    # param desired_units_sold int. Target number of units to sell in the new campaign.
    # returns float. Required amount of money to be invested.
    @staticmethod
    def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
        X = [[i] for i in units_sold]
        reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        reg.fit(X, marketing_expenditure)
        return float(reg.predict(desired_units_sold))

#For example, with the parameters below the function should return 250000.0.
print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

Comment: I think 250877 is close enough to 25000. It is less than 0.5% difference. The code seems right.

Comment: Maybe you can post process the output to round the number

Comment: your answer passes 1 test. if you round it to 25000, you pass another test, but fail the one you were previously passing. no idea how to pass the last test. it seems broken.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the solution because we search to predict X from y, and the label in this problem is units_sold.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

class MarketingCosts:

    # param marketing_expenditure list. Expenditure for each previous campaign.
    # param units_sold list. The number of units sold for each previous campaign.
    # param desired_units_sold int. Target number of units to sell in the new campaign.
    # returns float. Required amount of money to be invested.
    @staticmethod
    def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
        marketing_expenditure = marketing_expenditure.reshape(-1, 1)
        units_sold = units_sold.reshape(-1, 1)
        reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        reg.fit(marketing_expenditure , units_sold)
        return (desired_units_sold - reg.intercept_)/reg.coef_

#For example, with the parameters below the function should return 250000.0.
print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

Comment: This is the first correct answer. The point is that X = marketing_expenditure, Y=units_sold. However, you don't then use the predict function (which gives 250870). You are given 'desired_units' which is the Y variable and asked to find out the X variable. - This implies a*x + b = 60000. Now solve for x.

Comment: What's fundamentally different about OP's approach?  X = units sold, Y = marketing expenditure, then they're predicting given desired units.
Why is it not symmetrical when the X and Y's are swapped?

Comment: Ahhh! Google explains: "regression line minimizes the sum of the squares of the vertical errors. If you switch x and y then instead of vertical errors it will be horizontal errors."

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

class MarketingCosts:

    # param marketing_expenditure list. Expenditure for each previous campaign.
    # param units_sold list. The number of units sold for each previous campaign.
    # param desired_units_sold int. Target number of units to sell in the new campaign.
    # returns float. Required amount of money to be invested.
    @staticmethod
    def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
        marketing_expenditure = np.asarray(marketing_expenditure).reshape(-1, 1)
        units_sold = np.asarray(units_sold).reshape(-1, 1)
        reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        reg.fit(marketing_expenditure , units_sold)
        return np.float((desired_units_sold - reg.intercept_)/reg.coef_)

#For example, with the parameters below the function should return 250000.0.
print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I was rounding to solve the first test case and thus failing the second... This is a small sample, single variable regression so actually it looks like you can't use vanilla regression, but Theil-Sen regression. I checked the result and it comes to 250000.00003619, which you then just round.

Source:
https://gist.github.com/mfakbar/f97949299171c75e868a37f3f578fa54

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

class MarketingCosts:

    # param marketing_expenditure list. Expenditure for each previous campaign.
    # param units_sold list. The number of units sold for each previous campaign.
    # param desired_units_sold int. Target number of units to sell in the new campaign.
    # returns float. Required amount of money to be invested.
    @staticmethod
    def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
        y, x = np.array(marketing_expenditure), np.array(units_sold).reshape(-1, 1)
        regressor = linear_model.TheilSenRegressor(max_subpopulation=10)
        regressor.fit(x, y)
        desired_units_sold = np.array([desired_units_sold]).reshape(-1, 1)
        return float(round(regressor.predict(desired_units_sold).item()))

# For example, with the parameters below the function should return 250000.0.
print(MarketingCosts.desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

Comment: Can we get some more elaboration on why you can't use the default LinearRegression() of sklearn?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer which passes all tests:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):

    x = np.array(marketing_expenditure).reshape(-1, 1)
    y = np.array(units_sold).reshape(-1, 1)
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x , y)

    return (desired_units_sold - model.intercept_)/model.coef_
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

#### here is my answer that passes all testcases

You can find simple steps to perform a linear regression [**here**](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/?fbclid=IwAR1nzVlKrweua2MqQDnZ3AGSUHjrhMJBHp3fygHidqk5dWXPi-Pne_yyuck#:%7E:text=A%20regression%20coefficient%20is%20the,is%20the%20mean%20of%20x)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def desired_marketing_expenditure(marketing_expenditure, units_sold, desired_units_sold):
    s_x = sum(marketing_expenditure)
    s_y = sum(units_sold)
    xy = [] 
    for i in range (len(marketing_expenditure)):
        z= marketing_expenditure[i]*units_sold[i]
        xy.append(z)
    s_xy = sum(xy)
    sq_x = [number ** 2 for number in marketing_expenditure]
    s_sq_x = sum(sq_x)
    sq_y = [number ** 2 for number in units_sold]
    s_sq_y = sum(sq_y)   
    
    # calculating coefficients a and b for liner regression
    a=((s_y*s_sq_x) - (s_x*s_xy))/(len(marketing_expenditure)*s_sq_x - (s_x**2))
    b=(len(marketing_expenditure)*s_xy - (s_x*s_y)) / 
       (len(marketing_expenditure)*s_sq_x - (s_x**2))
    return (desired_units_sold-a)/b


#For example, with the parameters below, the function should return 250000.0
print(desired_marketing_expenditure(
    [300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000],
    [60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000],
    60000))
```

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/?fbclid=IwAR1nzVlKrweua2MqQDnZ3AGSUHjrhMJBHp3fygHidqk5dWXPi-Pne_yyuck#:~:text=A%20regression%20coefficient%20is%20the,is%20the%20mean%20of%20x